# Pad a string in DolphinDB

Tags: string-formatting, dolphindb, text-align, zero-padding

I wonder if there are any alternatives to the Python rjust or zfill in DolphinDB.

I want to add zeros(0) on the specified side of a string until it reaches the specified length. How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

For string

```
lpad(`Hello, 12, `0);
0000000Hello
rpad(`Hello, 12, `0);
Hello0000000
```

For decimal

```
decimalFormat(123,"00000");
00123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function lpad and rpad to pad a string with a specific set of characters.

Take lpad for example,

```
s = "123"
s = lpad(s, 5, "0")
```

The result is '00123'.